# How to count up in binary on a board of 8 LEDs - PIC

Tags: c, binary, pic, led

I have this program and I'm wanting to modify it so the LEDs count up in binary at a rate of 1Hz (1s).

```
#include <xc.h>           

void main(void) { 
    TRISD  = 0x00;          
    PORTD  = 0x00; 
    INTCON = 0xA0;          
    OPTION_REGbits.T0CS = 0;     
    OPTION_REGbits.PSA  = 0;     
    OPTION_REGbits.PS = 7;          
    while(1);           
} 

void interrupt myISR(void) { 
    if(TMR0IF) { 
        PORTD++; 
        INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;  
    }
}
```

I understand I will have to modify the `myISR` function so that `PORTD` increments after a certain amount of overflows and that a suitable preload value will be needed but in terms of counting in binary, what are the possible ways to go about this?

Comment: You don't show how the interrupt is invoked, but it would be usual to be a timer response with the desired period. If 1Hz is too slow for a timer, use a variable to count in the interrupt and when time is up, reset the count and increment the port value. Although incrementing a port value is not wise in a general sense, since the port may be write-only, or because reading the port may affect its behaviour. It is better (again generally) to use a variable for the LED pattern.

Comment: ... as for "counting in binary", incrementing a variable or register does exactly that, although the LEDs might have inverse logic.

Comment: @T Sijad, Your question needs to be asked in a better way. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Questions that involve Microchip controllers also need to specify the FULL part number of the device you seek an answer for and the frequency of the system oscillator. There are over 50 types of controllers that you could be using. The code posted contains some clues, a PIC16F877A is my best guess.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Also, @Dan1138, you're right, I should be more specific in the future but your guess is correct. I am using that exact PIC.

Comment: @T Sijad, At this point you should edit your own question to improve the content. At a minimum add comments at the beginning that state the file name, target controller, IDE version, compiler version. A description of the desired behavior is very helpful. The scope of your question is narrow enough that it is possible to post all the code, including how the configuration words are set and how the system clock is initialized (internal oscillator or external crystal, uses PLL or not, etc ...)

Answer (score 1):

If your Timer 0 Interrupt comes e.g every 100ms this example could help:

```
void interrupt myISR(void) {
    static uint8_t counter = 0;

    if(TMR0IF) 
    { 
        INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;  
        TMR0 = RELOAD_VALUE_100MS
        counter++;
        if (counter >= 10)
        {
            counter = 0;
            PORTD++; 
        }
    }
}
```